# Docker secrets and RSA keys

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-swarm

I have a Docker swarm and I would like to use a secret RSA key in a service to connect via SSH to another container.

My security policy is that all the secrets (passwords, keys, etc.) are stored on a different machine than the destination servers (the Swarm).

Actually (and I don't like it), in my Dockerfile I create a temporary directory `/run/secrets`:

```
mkdir -p /run/secrets
```

Then I create fake `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files:

```
touch /run/secrets/id_rsa
touch /run/secrets/id_rsa.pub
```

And now I create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /run/secrets/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
ln -s /run/secrets/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I'm doing this because I didn't find a way to copy the secrets in my `docker-entrypoint.sh`: in the entrypoint I'm not root so I can't copy in the `/root` directory.

So, I'm already using Docker secrets but the problem here is that the secrets inside the containers are in read-only. That impacts the usage of SSH:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0444 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

I can't modify the permissions of my `id_rsa` file since it's read-only.

Is there a workaround or just a really better way to do it ?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

I'm trying to change the way I build my Docker image in order to copy keys in the `/root/.ssh` directory.

Comment: In Dockerfile you can change the user with `USER` statement. Also, permission for ssh key should be `600` not `444` - `chmod 600 <PATH_TO_KEY>`

Comment: Yes, I know and that's my problem. With Docker's secrets I can't change the permission since they're readonly.

Comment: Could you please provide the Dockerfile?

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that my Dockerfile inherits the `postgres:9.6.5` image. I didn't find any reference to `USER` in it but I'm investigating :) Thanks for the little help!

Comment: Why are you copying the keys in entrypoint instead of when building an image?

Comment: Because I'll use the public key in another image/another service, within a Swarm. Also, I have several environments. My security policy is that all the secrets (passwords, keys, etc.) are stored on a different machine than the destination servers.

Comment: Ok, understood. Sorry, but no idea how can I help you then.

Comment: I understand the difficulty. Anyway, I don't think I'm on the right way :)

Comment: You are probably not ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating a stack with a compose file.
This gives you the option to alter the file permissions of your secrets.

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    secrets:
      - source: my_secret
        target: redis_secret
        uid: '103'
        gid: '103'
        mode: 0440
secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./my_secret.txt
  my_other_secret:
    external: true
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-2

Comment: Thanks! I saw that you  can run a service with option `--secret my_secret,mode=0400` for example.

Comment: Even if my problem is larger than my question, you're right and you answer my "real" question: the permissions on a RSA key.